# Diophantine equation: $2(x^3+xy+y^3)=3(x+y)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, diophantine-equations, integers

Here is a nice equation: $2(x^3+xy+y^3)=3(x+y)$ over $ \mathbb{Z}$ x $\mathbb{Z}$.
Any nice way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x+y$ is even, let $x+y=2a,xy=b$ where $a,b\in\mathbb Z$.

Notice that we have
$$(2a)^2-4b\ge 0\iff b\le a^2\tag1$$
since $x,y$ are roots of $X^2-2aX+b=0$.

Now, since we have
$$\begin{align}2(x^3+xy+y^3)=3(x+y)&\iff 2\{(x+y)((x+y)^2-3xy)+xy\}=3(x+y)\\&\iff 2\{2a(4a^2-3b)+b\}=6a\\&\iff b(6a-1)=8a^3-3a\end{align}$$
with $6a-1\not=0$, we have
$$b=\frac{8a^3-3a}{6a-1}\tag2$$
From $(1)$, we have
$$\frac{8a^3-3a}{6a-1}\le a^2\tag3$$
Here, let us separate it into cases :

(Case 1) If $6a-1\ge 0\iff a\ge 1/6$, then 
$$(3)\iff 8a^3-3a\le a^2(6a-1)\iff a(a-1)(2a+3)\le 0.$$
Hence, we have $1/6\le a\le 1$.

(Case 2) If $6a-1\lt 0\iff a\lt 1/6$, then 
$$(3)\iff 8a^3-3a\ge a^2(6a-1)\iff a(a-1)(2a+3)\ge 0.$$
Hence, we have $-3/2\le a\le 0$.

Since we can see every integer we get from $(3)$ is $a=0,\pm1$, the answer is 
$$(a,b)=(0,0),(1,1)\Rightarrow (x,y)=(0,0),(1,1).$$
(Here, note that $b=5/7$ is not an integer for $a=-1$.)

Comment: Nice. Probably easier to reason with the signs reversed: $$b=\frac{8a^3-3a}{6a-1}$$ Same logic, just probably a little clearer.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I agree with you:)

Comment: Note that there is hidden here a useful little identity $(x+y)^3=x^3+y^3+3xy(x+y)$ or $x^3+y^3=(x+y)^3-3xy(x+y)$ which is useful to have to hand if you are dealing with cubic problems like this one. It is also an identity which relates to the solution of cubic equations.

Comment: @MarkBennet: Thank you for pointing it out.